# SAGA/Cross Profiles not running correctly

Tags: qgis, saga, hydrology

I cannot get SAGA's Cross Profiles tool to run, it worked a few weeks ago when I discovered it.  I've removed QGIS as well as the appdata/local and roaming directories and updated to LTR 3.28.7 without any luck on that end.

Here is the error, I'm getting which I think is pretty generic:

```
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/matthewh/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BfTnyB/c061ddd31322423694b6e6b60fa6a63b/PROFILES.shp
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

[image]

I've uploaded the files I'm trying to process here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1exwZvec6iJBpl9Tl0W0wJgFeMWZ_HOMP?usp=sharing

Comment: Error messages should always be placed in the Question body as text. Images are not legible on all devices, and cannot be searched by others with the same problem.